# How do I add sidecar containers on the prometheus stable Helm Charts values.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently using the prometheus (NOT prometheus-operator, due to historical reasons) Helm charts in our on-premise Kubernetes cluster, and I'd like to deploy the Thanos sidecar.

How do I add the sidecar containers in the `values.yaml` file? Are there any examples on this that I can refer to? Seems like there are no documentation whatsoever regarding this, as pointed out by this https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/12815

Comment: Which helm chart are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the [comment](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/12815#issuecomment-528881504) said, the template is pretty simple.

```
  {{- if .Values.server.sidecarContainers }}
  {{- toYaml .Values.server.sidecarContainers | nindent 8 }}
  {{- end }}
```

You can put a values.yaml with your sidecar snippet like below:

```
server:
  sidecarContainers:
  - name: testSideCar
    image: alpine
```

And deploy with `helm install prom stable/prometheus -f values.yaml`. Then you can find your sidecar section in server deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: test-prometheus-server
      containers:
        - name: prometheus-server-configmap-reload
          image: "jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.3.0"

          <<... omitted ...>>

        - name: testSideCar
          image: alpine
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [configuration](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus#configuration) section of [stable/prometheus](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus) chart, you can add `server.sidecarContainers`

> `server.sidecarContainers` - array of snippets with your sidecar containers for prometheus server