# Add Sidecar container to running pod(s)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fluent-bit, sidecar

I have helm deployment scripts for a vendor application which we are operating. For logging solution, I need to add a sidecar container for fluentbit to push the logs to aggregated log server (splunk in this case).

Now to define this sidecar container, I want to avoid changing vendor defined deployment scripts. Instead i want some alternative way to attach the sidecar container to the running pod(s).

So far I have understood that sidecar container can be defined inside the same deployment script (deployment configuration).

Comment: You can attach the additional container in the `YAML` definition of your `Deployment`. This documentation could prove useful in this regard: [Multicontainer example from Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/). Please tell if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks @david. This has to be done before the deployment. I was wondering if I could attach a sidecar container to an already deployed (running) pod.

Answer (score 4):

Just for people, like me, landing here searching for what the title of the question says, a way of temporarily adding sidecar containers, since Kubernetes 1.25, the debugging feature has become stable!

**NOTE: If you have the same use case as the one stated in the question description, please read the other answers!**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container

So you can just run:

```
kubectl debug -it your-pod-with --image=busybox:1.28 --target=ephemeral-demo
```

But of course, this is not suitable for the OP, as this is for short-term debugging, and not to run processes.

Comment: It was in beta (and enabled by default) since Kubernetes 1.23

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question in the comments:

> thanks @david. This has to be done before the deployment. I was wondering if I could attach a sidecar container to an already deployed (running) pod.

**You can't attach the additional container to a running `Pod`**. You can update (patch) the resource definition. This will force the resource to be recreated with new specification.

There is a github issue about this feature which was closed with the following comment:

> After discussing the goals of SIG Node, **the clear consensus is that the containers list in the pod spec should remain immutable**. [#27140](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27140) will be better addressed by [kubernetes/community#649](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/649), which allows running an ephemeral debugging container in an existing pod. This will not be implemented.
>
> -- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Issues: Allow containers to be added to a running pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37838)*

---

Answering the part of the post:

> Now to define this sidecar container, I want to avoid changing vendor defined deployment scripts. Instead i want some alternative way to attach the sidecar container to the running pod(s).

Below I've included two methods to add a sidecar to a `Deployment`. **Both of those methods will reload the `Pods`** to match new specification:

- Use `$ kubectl patch`
- Edit the `Helm` Chart and use `$ helm upgrade`

In both cases, I encourage you to check how Kubernetes handles updates of its resources. You can read more by following below links:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tutorials: Kubernetes Basics: Update: Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/)*
- *[Medium.com: Platformer blog: Enable rolling updates in Kubernetes with zero downtime](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/enable-rolling-updates-in-kubernetes-with-zero-downtime-31d7ec388c81)*

---

---

#### Use `$ kubectl patch`

The way to completely avoid editing the Helm charts would be to use:

- `$ kubectl patch`

This method will "patch" the existing `Deployment/StatefulSet/Daemonset` and add the sidecar. The downside of this method is that it's not automated like Helm and you would need to create a "patch" for every resource (each `Deployment`/`Statefulset`/`Daemonset` etc.). In case of any updates from other sources like Helm, this "patch" would be overridden.

Documentation about updating API objects in place:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Tasks: Manage Kubernetes objects: Update api object kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)*

---

#### Edit the `Helm` Chart and use `$ helm upgrade`

This method will require editing the Helm charts. The changes made like adding a sidecar will persist through the updates. After making the changes you will need to use the `$ helm upgrade RELEASE_NAME CHART`.

You can read more about it here:

- *[Helm.sh: Docs: Helm: Helm upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/)*

Comment: Ultimately I think the helm option is the best solution. 
A flag can be added to the chart's values file so as to control the deployment of certain containers.
The flag's value can be left false so the default behavior is to not create the container and then just override the flag's value during a deployment or upgrade to have the container added to the new pod.

Answer (score 0):

A kubernetes ressource is immutable, as mention by [dawid-kruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12257134/dawid-kruk) . Therefore modifing the pod description will cause the containers to restart.

You can modify the pod using the `kubectl patch` command, don't forget to reapply the. Patch as necessary.

Alternatively The two following options will inject the sidecar without having to modify/fork upstream chart or mangling deployed ressources.

## #1 mutating admission controller

A mutating admission controller (webhook) can modify ressources see https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/

You can use a generic framework like opa.
Or a specific webhook like [fluentd-sidecar-injector](https://github.com/h3poteto/fluentd-sidecar-injector) (not tested)

## #2 support arbitrary sidecar in helm

You could submit a feature request to the chart mainter to supooort arbitrary sidecar injection, like in Prometheus, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62910122/1260896